# Input records not matching output records in python mapreduce

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a map reduce program in python. The mapper is working perfectly fine when i run it using -

```
cat input.csv|python mapper.py > output.tsv
```

But when i run it using the below command, i don't get the desired output -

```
nohup hadoop jar /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.0-mapr-1607.jar -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=queue_name -Dmapred.map.tasks=1000 -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0 -input /path/sample_reduce.csv -output /path/map_output -mapper "mapper_try.py" -reducer NONE -file mapper_try.py > mapp_try2.out &
```

It says that the job has been completed successfully, but i also get the following -

```
Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=1096
            Map output records=92
            Input split bytes=122610
            Spilled Records=0
            Failed Shuffles=0
            Merged Map outputs=0
            GC time elapsed (ms)=0
            CPU time spent (ms)=840560
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=353314721792
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=4310996582400
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=2036214005760
```

I am unable to fix the issue of my input records not matching the output records. The output files are all created, with 92 files having 1 row each but the other files being empty. Request help. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-mapper "python /path/to/mapper_try.py"
```

instead of:

```
-mapper "mapper_try.py"
```